# how to make proximity alert fire only once when enter radius?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created an app in which the user first has an option to add `latitude` and `longitude` to `SQLite` database to fire `Notification` when they enter registered area.

After that i have added marker using that `LatLng` saved in database. I have used Notification to show the alert.

**Problem**: My problem is it's keep firing notification if i stay for some time within the marker radius.

Anyone who knows a solution to make it fire only once if i enter the proximity and fire again when i re-enter the area only. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is just to save whether or not you have fired an notification, and then reset it when you first notice that you are outside the area:

```
bool notified = false;
if(inArea() && !notified)
    notify();
    notify = true;
else if(!inArea and notified)
   notified= false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference between Circle, center point and where it is present:

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");     
locationA.setLatitude(latitude_center); 
locationA.setLongitude(longitude_center);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");
locationB.setLatitude(lat_current); 
locationB.setLongitude(lng_current);

float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

if(radius < distance){
// fire alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably ought to look at including a degree of [hysterisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) ... an overlap between when you enter the area and when you leave.  You need two radii: the smaller defines when you have entered the target area; the larger defines when you leave it.  You then incorporate these into something similar to [Astrogat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31514984/2096401)'s answer:

```
bool notified = false;
...
if(inArea(innerRadius) && !notified) {
    notify();
    notify = true;
} else if(!inArea(outerRadius) && notified) {
   notified= false;
}
```

The advantage over a single radius is that this will prevent you toggling between "in" and "out" when you're just on the edge of the target area.

Note, also, that the `notified` variable will need to persist across calls to the "should we notify" logic.